# Is there a way in Safari to default a new tab's focus to the search box?

Tags: macos, safari

In the safari browser is there a tweak you can make so that when a new tab is created the main focus point jumps to the search box in the browser or at least to the address bar instead of focusing to the home page?

Comment: What is the behaviour on your system?

Comment: Can you update your accepted answer to the more up-to-date and relevant one by Thorsten? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38244977/706771

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Glims can do this: "Sets the focus on the search field when opening a new window"
[Link](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/27708/glims)

Answer (score 10):

You can modify Safari like this:

```
Settings -> General -> New tabs open with: Empty page
```

This will make the cursor start in the address bar. Which in turn can be used to query a search engine or to directly enter an URL.

If you want the tab to become active immediately then you may want to do:

```
Settings -> Tabs -> Check: "When a new tab or window opens, make it active"
```

The default on my system was that the cursor was in the search box within the home page. The home page was: http://search.strtpoint.com/ and "open new tabs with" was "Homepage"

Comment: 5 years after answering a 5 year old question, this is still incredibly helpful and way too buried. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it. That would be up to the browser.

Comment: that's why I'm asking if there is a browser tweak

Comment: @BeagleDude What do you mean? Via JavaScript? Compiling your own version to do it?